# Consecutive points alternating up and down in a list

Tags: c#

I have an observation list and want to find consecutive alternating up and down values for a given count. For example when observation list is `{ 1, 3, 4, 2, 7, 5, 6, 8, 1, 2, 4}` and given count for check is `4`, method should return a `list<list>>` as `{{3,4,2,7}, {2,7,5,6}}`.

I already create method as below, but want to do this with linq or more efficent way.Could anybody help?

```
List<List<decimal>> GetinvalidObservationMatrix(List<decimal> observationList, int checkedCount)
    {
        List<List<decimal>> invalidObservationMatrix = new List<List<decimal>>();

        while (observationList.Count >= checkedCount)
        {
            List<decimal> currentObservationList = observationList.Take(checkedCount).ToList();
            bool isGreater = false;
            bool isPreviousGreater = false;

            for (int i = 1; i < checkedCount - 1; i++)
            {
                isPreviousGreater = isGreater;

                if (currentObservationList[i] == currentObservationList[i - 1] || currentObservationList[i] == currentObservationList[i + 1])
                {
                    break;
                }

                if (currentObservationList[i] > currentObservationList[i - 1])
                {
                    isGreater = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    isGreater = false;
                }

                if (i != 1 && isGreater == isPreviousGreater)
                {
                    break;
                }

                if (isGreater)
                {
                    if (currentObservationList[i + 1] >= currentObservationList[i])
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (currentObservationList[i + 1] <= currentObservationList[i])
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (i == checkedCount - 2)
                {
                    invalidObservationMatrix.Add(currentObservationList);
                }
            }

            observationList = observationList.Skip(1).ToList();
        }

        return invalidObservationMatrix;
    }
```

Comment: Why isn´t the `1` in the first result?

Comment: @HimBromBeere - presumably because that would be up (1-3), up (3-4), down (4-2) which isn't "alternating up and down"

Comment: Why do you want a linq-solution? I doubt it will be any faster at all - not mentioning that it will probably be very hard to understand. In fact LINQ isn´t good in looking backwards and forwards within a collection, which implies some kind of index-based access.

Comment: Could you explain more about what you are trying to achieve from the data, maybe with some more example test cases?  There are some neat techniques you can use to do work such as this, I'm just not clear why you expect that output.

Comment: You can have a look at `IEnumerable<T>.Aggregate(...)` but you would have to use out-of-aggregate "memorycells" for state and essentially the same (or very similar) if/elseif/else constructs inside - just leave it as is.

Comment: Aim for readability, not for efficence, until you actually measure your "inefficent" code and realize it's a bottleneck for your program. It seems you are working with lists of a few elements: the less efficent algorithm you can write will hardly have any *noticeable* impact on your program speed

Comment: @Trevor - This is for SPC (statistical process control), there is a rule if observation values up and down consecutively for several times, process is not in statistical control. GetinvalidObservationMatrix returns tihs values but it is very simple and too much if else cases, which I don't want to use.

Comment: @gambler So do you actually need to output the alternating sequences, or is it enough to know that an alternating sequence of at least four elements exists?

Comment: @HimBromBeere @PatrickArtner As OP only needs comparisons between consecutive values, a `.Skip().Zip()` is enough in this case.  No need for `.Aggregate()`.

Answer (score 0):

Accepting that this does not actually answer the original question, this code will find all the alternating sequences.

```
void FindAlternativeSequences()
{
    var observations = new List<int>() { 1, 3, 4, 2, 7, 5, 6, 8, 1, 2, 4 };
    const int threshold = 4;

    var consecutivePairs = observations.Skip(1).Zip(observations, (a, b) => Math.Sign(a - b)).Zip(GetAlternator(), (x, y) => x * y);
    var runs = FindEqualRuns(consecutivePairs).Select(t => new Tuple<int, int>(t.Item1, t.Item2 + 1)).ToList();
}

public IEnumerable<int> GetAlternator()
{
    int value = -1;
    int sanity = Int32.MaxValue;
    while (--sanity > 0)
    {
        value *= -1;
        yield return value;
    }
    yield break;
}

public IEnumerable<Tuple<int,int>> FindEqualRuns(IEnumerable<int> enumerable)
{
    int previousValue = 0;
    int index = 0;
    int startIndex = 0;
    bool foundAnElement = false;

    foreach ( var value in enumerable )
    {
        if (index == 0) previousValue = value;
        foundAnElement = true;

        if (!value.Equals(previousValue))
        {
            // This is a difference, return the previous run
            yield return new Tuple<int, int>(startIndex, index - startIndex);
            startIndex = index;
            previousValue = value;
        }

        index++;
    }

    if (foundAnElement)
    {
        yield return new Tuple<int, int>(startIndex, index - startIndex);
    }

    yield break;
}
```

**What it does**

The code finds all alternating sequences of any length, starting with either an up-step or a down-step.  It then populates the `runs` variable with tuples where `Item1` is the index of the first element in the sequence, and `Item2` is the length of the alternating sequence.

This `runs` variable can then be used to ask a wide range of questions about the data, such as deriving the answer to the original question.  The `runs` output by itself does not return the alternating sequences, but identifies where and how long they are.

**How it works**

The bulk of the of the work is done in one line:

```
var consecutivePairs = observations.Skip(1).Zip(observations, (a, b) => Math.Sign(a - b)).Zip(GetAlternator(), (x, y) => x * y);
```

This zips together the `observations` along with `observations-skip-1` to give pairs of consecutive values.  These pairs are then subtracted and run through the `Math.Sign()` function to give `+1`, `-1` or `0` for whether the first is greater, the second is greater, or if they are the same.  This output has runs of `+1` or `-1` for increasing or decreasing sequences.  It's also one element shorter than `observations`.

```
observations =>         { 1,  3,  4,  2,  7,  5,  6,  8,  1,  2,  4 }
Output from 1st .Zip() => {  1,  1, -1,  1, -1,  1,  1, -1,  1,  1 }
```

This result is then zipped and multiplied by an alternating `+1, -1, +1, -1, ...` sequence.  This results in runs of +1 or -1 indicating consecutive alternating up-steps and down-steps.

```
observations =>         { 1,  3,  4,  2,  7,  5,  6,  8,  1,  2,  4 }
Output from 1st .Zip() => {  1,  1, -1,  1, -1,  1,  1, -1,  1,  1 }
Output from 2nd .Zip() => {  1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,  1,  1,  1, -1 }
```

The line `var runs = FindEqualRuns(consecutivePairs).Select(t => new Tuple<int, int>(t.Item1, t.Item2 + 1)).ToList();` then uses another function to find all the consecutive runs or either +1, -1, or 0 in that set, giving the `startIndex` and `count`.  Because this gives us runs against the pairs enumeration (which is one element shorter than the original `observations`), we do need to add 1 to each count.  For example, if it finds a run of 3 elements in the pairs enumeration, this represents a run of 4 elements in `observations`.

The output in `runs` gives the detail on the start and length of all the alternating sequences in the data.

```
runs => { {0, 2}, {1, 6}, {6, 4}, {9, 2} }
```

So there is:

- a sequence of length 2, starting at the 0th index => `{ 1, 3 }`
- a sequence of length 6, starting at the 1st index => `{ 3, 4, 2, 7, 5, 6 }`
- a sequence of length 4, starting at the 6th index => `{ 6, 8, 1, 2 }`
- a sequence of length 2, starting at the 9th index => `{ 2, 4 }`

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation and code, that is a good pattern and useful for my case